# Whats the point of a device driver if normal programs and drivers both use system calls

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, privileges, drivers

If a kernel driver is running in kernel space or Ring0, then why is it still subject to a system call rather than performing the operation iteself. My question really is why have a kernel driver if both user mode and a kernel driver both have to use system calls? Why not just have a regular program that uses system calls instead of a kernel driver.

Comment: What driver architecture are you referring to here? Windows? Linux? Something else?

Comment: oh sorry about that. Im reffering to linux kernel drivers

Comment: What makes you think that kernel modules are "subject to a system call"? (What precisely do you mean by that?)

Comment: System calls mediate between user space and kernel. Drivers are part of kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel module (driver) doesn't use system calls since it's operate on ring 0. it replaces (or adds to) existing system calls, so that when a device that uses that module calls for the operation (calls for a system call), the kernel function which is called is the one defined by the module and not the default kernel function.

Comment: That description of how kernel modules work is significantly inaccurate. Kernel modules do not (and, in fact, _cannot_) override system calls.

Comment: @duskwuff, while I agree in general on the comment, there is a possible hack to override system call from kernel module.

Comment: @0andriy That method exists, but it is not used in the Linux kernel.